# What is the largest value of Facebook SDK score int?

Tags: facebook, sdk

Simple question I cannot seem to find an answer to anywhere:

What is the largest value I can have for a score in the Facebook SDK score integer?  Ie: how many bits is the integer? 32? 64?  I cannot find this anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the answer is 64-bits, but can someone point me to a reference please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Integers in the graph API are 32 bits long and are signed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/property-types/#simple), so the maximum value is  `2147483647`.

Comment: Thanks. But I read somewhere that FB was moving IDs, which are also integer to 64 bit only. So that does not apply here? That is my confusion.

Comment: @MajorHavoc No, it doesn't apply. Facebook just treats ids's as strings, so they can be any length: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: Followed the link (missed it there at first) and see the reference. Thank you.